# JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200) in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working with a Xamarin Android project using Visual Studio IDE version 7.7. I am getting this error after 6 times of my navigation between two activities. I don't know exactly how to resolve this issue. After googling I can understand it will be a cause of more global references.

```
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] weak global reference table dump:
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]   Last 10 entries (of 51200):
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51199: 0x176d4400 android.widget.Button
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51198: 0x15f13190 java.lang.String "https://atozfurn... (78 chars)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51197: 0x168ab800 android.widget.TextView
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51196: 0x15abdb80 com.bumptech.glide.request.target.DrawableImageViewTarget
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51195: 0x14e3a160 java.lang.Integer
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51194: 0x14f22c00 android.widget.ImageView
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51193: 0x159dec00 android.widget.ImageView
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51192: 0x17241400 android.widget.Button
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51191: 0x18675800 android.widget.Button
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51190: 0x14e9ee20 java.lang.String "https://atozfurn... (112 chars)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]   Summary:
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of md5ad7193dba8ab38209230f445b14ed0f9.MainActivity
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of md5fa1ac5b576d3ee42b2a11a88c1a40164.HomeActivity (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of md5d62d93d8fe9047f7cede206e3c4c9b86.SliderAdapter (6 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        24 of mono.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor (24 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of md517e16c37e5a39ffebf34f8de696179e6.HomeFragment_SliderTimer (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         9 of android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (9 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.support.design.widget.TabLayout (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        35 of android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl (35 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater (6 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        78 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (78 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        20 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (20 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        36 of android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (36 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenu (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        14 of android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar (14 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       350 of mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor (350 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawerArrowDrawable (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        18 of md59ebb8a1c6f05fa0e4236113878bde706.BadgeDrawable (18 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of mono.android.support.design.widget.NavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of mono.android.animation.AnimatorEventDispatcher (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       707 of com.bumptech.glide.request.target.DrawableImageViewTarget (707 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of md517e16c37e5a39ffebf34f8de696179e6.HomeFragment (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.widget.SearchView (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of android.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        21 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton (21 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         5 of md59ebb8a1c6f05fa0e4236113878bde706.ViewPagerCustomDuration (5 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of md5fa1ac5b576d3ee42b2a11a88c1a40164.CategoryActivity (6 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        12 of android.widget.GridView (12 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior (6 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of md5e4befe2abca7f73da05d796cea9fa280.RangeSliderControl (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of md5d62d93d8fe9047f7cede206e3c4c9b86.CAtegoryAdapter (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of md5d62d93d8fe9047f7cede206e3c4c9b86.CategoryListAdapter (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        12 of mono.android.widget.AbsListView_OnScrollListenerImplementor (12 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        49 of md5d62d93d8fe9047f7cede206e3c4c9b86.CAtegoryAdapter_ViewHolder (49 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of java.lang.Class (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      4938 of java.lang.String (4938 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (1440 elements) (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (1764 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (1836 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (3480 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (5016 elements) (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (5040 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (6912 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (7392 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (7740 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (7896 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of byte[] (8464 elements) (6 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         5 of byte[] (9216 elements) (5 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (9460 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (9632 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (9680 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of byte[] (10080 elements) (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (10816 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (12544 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (14880 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        11 of byte[] (15876 elements) (11 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        21 of byte[] (16384 elements) (21 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (17280 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         9 of byte[] (20736 elements) (9 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (21828 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (24964 elements) (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        27 of byte[] (26244 elements) (27 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (32256 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (32448 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (34848 elements) (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (35344 elements) (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        17 of byte[] (36864 elements) (17 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (38416 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (44100 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (46656 elements) (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (47808 elements) (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (57984 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (79488 elements) (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (82368 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (82944 elements) (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of byte[] (92984 elements) (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of byte[] (108000 elements) (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (125316 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         5 of byte[] (270400 elements) (5 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       167 of byte[] (328560 elements) (167 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (419580 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         9 of byte[] (977416 elements) (9 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       135 of java.lang.Integer (135 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of java.util.Timer (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        33 of java.lang.DexCache (33 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         9 of android.widget.ProgressBar (9 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         8 of com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater (8 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        12 of android.widget.FrameLayout (12 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      2894 of android.widget.Button (2894 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      4907 of android.widget.TextView (4907 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      1802 of android.widget.ImageView (1802 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         9 of android.widget.ListView (9 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         5 of android.view.DisplayListCanvas (5 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      1206 of android.widget.LinearLayout (1206 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of android.graphics.Matrix (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.widget.ScrollView (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       117 of android.widget.RelativeLayout (117 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         9 of android.content.res.Resources (9 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.util.DisplayMetrics
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.os.Looper (1 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.graphics.Bitmap$Config
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         8 of android.content.Intent (8 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        25 of android.graphics.Bitmap (25 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of android.app.FragmentManagerImpl (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.os.Handler (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        18 of android.view.animation.AnimationSet (18 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.view.ViewConfiguration
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of android.util.TypedValue (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         7 of android.graphics.Path (7 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of android.graphics.Paint (50 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        18 of android.animation.ObjectAnimator (18 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of android.view.ContextThemeWrapper (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         9 of android.app.AlertDialog (9 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.os.Bundle (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of android.os.AsyncTask$Status (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        38 of android.graphics.Rect (38 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     32342 of android.view.RenderNode (32342 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        25 of android.graphics.RectF (25 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       651 of android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable (651 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.graphics.Paint$Align
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of android.graphics.Paint$Style (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of android.content.res.TypedArray (4 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser (2 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        13 of android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl (13 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         8 of android.content.res.Resources$Theme (8 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] 
[art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Runtime aborting...
[art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Aborting thread:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you what it is.  Fixing it is harder.  When you use JNI (that's the Java Native Interface, how it calls C code), you have to keep references to the Java heap.  There's a limit to how many of them you can have.  There's separate limits for strong and weak references, the limit for weak references is 51200.  You have more than that.

The only solution is to reduce the number of references.  The real question is why do you have so many?  I see 3 instances of HomeActivity, so a memory leak is likely.  I also see 32K render nodes, I'm not even sure how you'd manage to do that.  I see thousands of text views-  the only idea I have other than massive memory leaks is that you're making massively long views and not using recyclierview/listview/gridview, which is a bad idea anyway

Comment: Thanks for your information. I am using gridView and listview in second activity. In first activity I am having custom horizontal scroll view which I am inflating using view inflater. Intense use of these two activity causes this crash. Also I do not understand what is render notes. Can you give any information on that.

Comment: RenderNodes have to do with the internal rendering system of Android-  how views actually draw to the screen.  So seeing thousands of them around is very unusual.  Dozens to hundreds wouldn't be concerning

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it. Somewhere in my code I am creating HomeActivity instance multiple times instead of finishing it. Now its working fine. But I really want to know what is render nodes? I don't have any idea on that. Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a decent description of it.  https://medium.com/@workingkills/understanding-the-renderthread-4dc17bcaf979